# Панели (panel) и разделители (splitter) c#

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме три панели разделенные двумя сплиттерами. 
Пусть порядок расположения элементов слева направо: `panel1`, `splitter1`, `panel2`, `splitter2`, `panel3`.

При перемещении `splitter1`, автоматически меняет положение `splitter2`, соответственно изменяя размер `panel3`.

Как сделать, чтобы при движении `splitter1`, `splitter2` оставался на своем месте?

Comment: Это у вас Winforms или WPF?

Comment: Речь идет о winforms

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно! С небольшой поправкой,если я не ошибаюсь. порядок добавления на форму следующий: p1,s1,p3,s2,p2. В таком случае все работает,как должно!

Comment: перенес комментарии в ответ, и немного дополнил возможными неприятностями такого решения

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам второй сплиттер в таком случае ?

Правильнее было бы использовать `TableLayoutPanel`, сделать в ней 2 столбца. В первом поместить две панели и сплиттер между ними. Во второй столбец поместите третью панель. И обоим столбцам задайте фиксированный размер по ширине в %.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сплиттер второй, чтобы иметь возможность отрегулировать ширину каждой из 3х панелей.Вариант с tablelayoutpanel хорош, однако хочется понять, есть ли решение вопроса именно для тех элементов,что я указал.

Answer (score 1):

Splitter2 зависит от Splitter1, по этому Splitter2 всегда двигается когда двигаешь Splitter1. Если хочешь не зависимую сплиттеры, придется делать свой сплиттер.

Comment: Спасибо! Свой сплиттер пока не под силу-опыта ноль.А нельзя ли как-то среагировать на перемещение splitter1 и заморозить,если можно так сказать, позицию splitter2, на время перемещения splitter1?

Answer (score 1):

Для получения желаемого эффекта нужно добавлять элементы в определенном порядке и корректировать свойство `Dock`.

Порядок добавления элементов на форму от края в центр:

panel1 (Dock = Left)
splitter1 (Dock = Left)
panel12 (Dock = Right)
splitter2 (Dock = Right)
panel3 (Dock = Fill)

Т.к. сплитеры прижимаются к крайним панелям, они не будут влиять друг на друга при изменении положения на форме. Для вертикального размещения заменяем Left => Up, Right => Down.

Как всегда не без ложки дегтя. Такой вариант плохо подходит для контейнера переменного размера, т.к. ширина крайних панелей не будет меняться автоматически пропорционально размеру контейнера, а следовательно возможна ситуация, когда при уменьшении окна левая и правая панели наложатся друг на друга, скрывая и среднюю панель и сплитеры. Для исправления ситуации нужно дописать обработку изменения размера внешнего контейнера, в которой предусмотреть соответствующее изменение размеров крайних панелей. Положение сплитеров и размер центральной панели подстроятся автоматически, благодаря свойству Dock.